# How to create new nodes by parameters

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I want to create new node and its properties by passing parameters to it using cypher queries:

```
@app.route('/enter',methods=['post'])
def enter_products():
     results = graph.cypher.execute("CREATE (a:Products{"name","age"})")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass in a map as parameters, each entry in the parameter map is available as `{key}` parameter in the query:

```
@app.route('/enter',methods=['post'])
def enter_products():
     params = {"data": {"name":"Gokul","age":23}}
     results = graph.cypher.execute("CREATE (a:Products {data})",params)
```

Comment: I updated the map syntax to python (I think). Do you get any error message?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>